# Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Assume we have the following suspend function:

```
suspend fun doSomething(): List<MyClass> { ... }
```

If I want to call this function in one of my existing Java classes (which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now) and get its return value I have to provide a `Continuation<? super List<MyClass>>` as its parameter (Obviously).

My question is, How can I implement one. Specially its `getContext` getter.

Comment: I would do anything possible to avoid having to do this; I wouldn't expect it to work very effectively.  For example, you could add another Kotlin function to launch the coroutine however you think is appropriate, that isn't a suspend fun, and call that from Java.

Comment: I used to have [Java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51808992/kotlin-suspend-fun/51811597#51811597) that managed to create an implementation of `Continuation` and call a `suspend fun`, but in Kotlin 1.3 `Continuation` declares `resumeWith(Result)`, where `Result` is a discriminated union of the result and an `internal class Failure` and there's just no way to supply that from Java, save for using reflection to access private members in Kotlin implementation.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

First, add `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` module to your dependencies. In your Kotlin file define the following async function that corresponds to Java style of writing async APIs:

```
fun doSomethingAsync(): CompletableFuture<List<MyClass>> =
    GlobalScope.future { doSomething() }
```

Now use `doSomethingAsync` from Java in the same way as you are using other asynchronous APIs in the Java world.

Comment: why is this not marked as the answer?? worked like a charm.

Comment: Is it possible to call from java the next kotlin code: GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)... ?

Comment: Not work on Android 6.0.  Error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture;

Comment: You represent it as any other future type and you are using in your Java code. We have built-in support for conversion into CompletableFuture, ListenableFuture, Rx Single, Reactor Mono. You can write your own, too.

Comment: Worked perfectly. My only problem is how to test it in kotlin using mockito2, verify is never beeing called :/

Comment: Note: this requires API level 24 or above.

Comment: check my answer for every android API

Comment: use jdk7 for older APIs

Comment: "Now use doSomethingAsync from Java in the same way as you are using other asynchronous APIs in the Java world." How???

Comment: using Dispatchers.Main is typically what would be wanted when calling from java:

fun doSomethingAsync(): CompletableFuture<List<MyClass>> =
    GlobalScope.future(Dispatchers.Main) { doSomething() }

Comment: Though that the main problem with Kotlin coroutines is that 4 years old code (strict and simple as hell) from coroutine author highlights with warning about `delicate api` in ide. So one need to figure out is it something changed for this 4 years before using this code.

Comment: @lehvolk have you found anything about this? is it possible to use this approach now? My IDE also returns Warnings about delicate api

Comment: @pampastu I stayed with suggested `delicate API`. From my prospective I see no side effects.

Comment: @lehvolk `delicate api` should be referring to the use of `GlobalScope`. You can create a coroutine scope within your class and you will be fine.

Comment: I tried this way. It is working fine. Able to get return data in a blocking way by calling async function. But if that suspend function has another async call, it is not working. I mean function returns immediately (not blocking till the result is received). Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Also, how can I  get a success/failure callback if we call this Kotlin suspend function from Java this way?

Answer (score 17):

If you dont want to use `org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8`, I have a new idea.

Write below code in your kotlin project.

```kotlin
@JvmOverloads
fun <R> getContinuation(onFinished: BiConsumer<R?, Throwable?>, dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default): Continuation<R> {
    return object : Continuation<R> {
            override val context: CoroutineContext
                get() = dispatcher

            override fun resumeWith(result: Result<R>) {
                onFinished.accept(result.getOrNull(), result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
    }
}
```

I wrote it in my `Coroutines` class

Then you can call your suspend function like:

```java
Coroutines coroutines = new Coroutines();  // My coroutines utils class
UserUtils.INSTANCE.login("user", "pass", coroutines.getContinuation(
    (tokenResult, throwable) -> {
        System.out.println("Coroutines finished");
        System.out.println("Result: " + tokenResult);
        System.out.println("Exception: " + throwable);
    }
));
```

login() function is a suspend function.
`suspend fun login(username: String, password: String): TokenResult`

For your code, you can:

```java
doSomething(getContinuation((result, throwable) -> { 
       //TODO
}));
```

Besides, you may want to run your callback code in a different thread (e.g. Main thread), just use `launch(Dispathers.Main)` to wrap `resumeWith()`

```java
...
        override fun resumeWith(result: Result<R>) {
            launch(Dispathers.Main) {
                onFinished.accept(result.getOrNull(), result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
        }
...
```

---

Update: My friend has developed a plugin [kotlin-jvm-blocking-bridge](https://github.com/Him188/kotlin-jvm-blocking-bridge) that can **automatically generate** blocking bridges for calling suspend functions from Java with minimal effort, also give it a try.

Comment: awesome!!! this is a workaround to call coroutine inside java for interopability

Comment: Just like Roman's answer, this also requires API 24 or higher

Comment: @Samuel Maybe you can replace BiConsumer and Lambda by your own interface and anonymous class to make it compatible with old Android SDK (not tested)

Answer (score 12):

For coroutines 1.3.0 use this:

```
BuildersKt.launch(GlobalScope.INSTANCE,
                Dispatchers.getMain(),//context to be ran on
                CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
                (coroutineScope, continuation) -> suspendFunction(arguments)
        );
```

For java < 8:

```
BuildersKt.launch(
        GlobalScope.INSTANCE,
        Dispatchers.getMain(),//context to be ran on
        CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
        new Function2<CoroutineScope, Continuation<? super Unit>, Unit/*or your return type here*/>() {
            @Override
            public Unit/*or your return type here*/ invoke(CoroutineScope coroutineScope, Continuation<? super Unit> continuation) {
                //do what you want
                return Unit.INSTANCE; //or something with the defined type
            }
        }
);
```

My gradle file:

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.50"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.0"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.0"
```

Kotlin uses static classes for extension functions, launch is an extension function, so it is defined in BuildersKt. The first parameter is the target of the extension function, the rest are the parameters from the extension functions.

Comment: This approach is useless because you can't resume the continuation, it takes an inline class that you can't access from Java.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you want to use Deferred you can use BuildersKt.async instead of launch, this is how coroutines work.

Comment: `// do what you want` -- you can't do what you want here because you must supply a continuation that expects to be resumed with the return type of the called function, but you don't have such a continuation and your answer doesn't show how to construct it from Java. The continuation you get from `launch` is just the completion continuation, the one you invoke with `Unit` when the whole coroutine is done.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik you can try to pass the continuation on the lambda there as the last parameter of your suspendFunction().

i.e., (coroutineScope, continuation) -> suspendFunction(arguments, continuation)

Comment: @Dragos Rachieru I like this solution however I'm not sure how to use this approach in methods with a return type. I.e. public MyObject getMyObject() - MyObject Id like to return depends on the data that comes from suspend function. Unfortunately I can't return from inside the BuildersKt.launch{}. Can you help me solve it?

Comment: @shtas you can't return from a launch as it can run on a separate thread from where you called the `launch`, `launch` returns a `Job` if you want to cancel or check if the coroutine is still running

Comment: Worked for me, but like this ---- BuildersKt.launch((CoroutineScope) GlobalScope.INSTANCE,
                    (CoroutineContext) Dispatchers.getMain(),
                    CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
                    (coroutineScope, continuation) ->
                            suspendFunction(arguments)
            );

Answer (score 3):

I created interface class based on @Kenvix answer to make it compatible with old Android SDK (lower than API 24)

```
interface CoroutineCallback<RESULT> {

companion object {

    @JvmOverloads
    fun <R> call(
        callback: CoroutineCallback<R>,
        dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
    ): Continuation<R> {
        return object : Continuation<R> {
            override val context: CoroutineContext
                get() = dispatcher

            override fun resumeWith(result: Result<R>) {
                callback.onComplete(result.getOrNull(), result.exceptionOrNull())
            }
        }
    }
}

 fun onComplete(result: RESULT?, error: Throwable?)
}
```

usage

```
class kotlinClass {
  suspend doSomething(foo, bar) : FooBar {}
}


class javaClass {
  void doSomething(){
   kotlinClassObject.doSomething("foo", "bar", CoroutineCallback.Companion.call((fooBar, error) -> { 
     //do something with result or error
   }));
  }
}
```

now call suspend function from any java class by passing `CoroutineCallback`