# How to call Kotlin suspending coroutine function from Java 7

Tags: java, android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm trying to call Kotlin function from Java 7. I'm using coroutines and this called function is suspending, for example:

```
suspend fun suspendingFunction(): Boolean {
    return async { longRunningFunction() }.await()
}

suspend fun longRunningFunction() : Boolean {
    delay(400)
    return true
}
```

I was using coroutines in version 0.25.3 and I could emulate simple Java callback style by passing `Continuation<U>` instance as an argument to suspending function, e.g.

```java
CoroutinesKt.suspendingFunction(new Continuation<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
        return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume(Boolean value) {
        doSomethingWithResult(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeWithException(@NotNull Throwable throwable) {
        handleException(throwable);
    }
});
```

However, after updating to fully stable 1.0.1 release, I think it's no longer possible. Let's say updated version of suspending function looks like that:

```
suspend fun suspendingFunction(): Boolean {
    return GlobalScope.async { longRunningFunction() }.await()
}
```

`Continuation<U>` now uses `Result` class, which seems to be unusable from Java (which makes sense as it is inline class). I was trying to use some subclass of `Continuation` from coroutines but they are all internal or private.

I know that usually it is [advised to transform coroutine to `CompletableFuture`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class), but I'm on Android, which means Java 7 only. Simple `Future` on the other hand is too dumb as I don't want to check periodically if function is finished - I just want to be called when it is finished. And I would really like to avoid adding new libraries or many additional classes/methods.

**Is there any simple way to call suspending function directly from Java 7?**

As Kotlin tries to be very interoperable with Java I would imagine there would be some easy way to do that, but I'm yet to find it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have several options depending on your environment.

1. If you are using `RxJava2` in the project, the module `kotlinx-coroutines-rx2` has utility functions to convert back and forth between coroutines and Rx datatypes.

**Example**

```
suspend fun sayHello(): String {
    delay(1000)
    return "Hi there"
}

fun sayHelloSingle(): Single<String> = GlobalScope.rxSingle { sayHello() }
```

2. Otherwise, you could add a new `Continuation` class that matches the definition of the old one and is also useful in the Java side.

**Example (Kotlin side)**

```
abstract class Continuation<in T> : kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<T> {
    abstract fun resume(value: T)
    abstract fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable)
    override fun resumeWith(result: Result<T>) = result.fold(::resume, ::resumeWithException)
}
```

**Example (Java side)**

```
sayHello(new Continuation<String>() {
    @Override
    public CoroutineContext getContext() {
        return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void resume(String value) {
        doSomethingWithResult(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void resumeWithException(@NotNull Throwable throwable) {
        doSomethingWithError(throwable);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! While I don't use RxJava, handling `Result` class on Kotlin side is very good idea. And one additional class is small price to pay.

Comment: Great response. Rx is good and clean approach to handle suspend calls inside java classes

Comment: If I'm calling this from a Java `Activity` should I still be using `return EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE;`? or is there a better `Context` to use?

Comment: This answer is now outdated, the `Continuation` interface has changed and now has a single method `resumeWith` that takes an inline class on the Kotlin side, it can represent either success or failure but you can't distinguish them because you have no access to the private classes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the continuation will come up as an Object that is non null but actually it can be null and will be you Object, in this example a String.

Comment: @NathanSchwermann If the suspendable function throws an exception, the continuation is resumed with `kotlin.Result$Failure`, which is an `internal class`.

Comment: Great! It worked `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`, `kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.6`

Comment: For RxJava you can simply call `rxSingle { sayHello() }`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [BuildersKt](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/src/Builders.kt). That is already included in the  `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.0"`

```
    BuildersKt.launch(
            GlobalScope.INSTANCE,
            (CoroutineContext) Dispatchers.getMain(),
            CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
            (Function2<CoroutineScope, Continuation<? super Unit>, Unit>) (coroutineScope, continuation) -> {
                // your code here
                return Unit.INSTANCE;
            }
    );
```

Comment: how do I switch dispatcher context inside the result block (your code here)? I need to read the data from the db on the background thread but afterwards display it to the user (android uI).