# How to convert Flow into Flowable?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2, kotlin-coroutines

I've just added

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-rx2:1.3.3"
```

to the project. And I have `suspend fun foo(): Flow<Bar>` in class A (from external package).

I need to get `Flowable<Bar>` to use in java.
I'd like to use extention `fun A.fooRx(): Flowable<Bar>` if possible.

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2

Comment: @akarnokd  I googled it already and I have no idea how to use it. I need an exaple.

Comment: Like `suspend fun A.fooRx() : Flowable<Bar> = this.foo().toFlowable()`?

Comment: Ok, how to use suspend function in java?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887677/61158

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803893/61158

Comment: Anyway it doesn't seems to be the answer to my question.

Comment: What control do you have over the sources? Can you add Kotlin code or are you limited to Java only?

Comment: I need to convert `suspend fun foo(): Flow<Bar>` to `fun fooRx(): Flowable<Bar>` adding extention for class A. I found rxFlowable() method in the library but as the same I am not sure how to correctly use it.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is given my responses above. You use `asFlowable`in Kotlin to get `Flowable` in Kotlin. Do you need this `Flowable` to be accessed from Java code?

Comment: Here is an SO answer about mimicking the continuation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033955/61158

Comment: @akarnokd The answers you link are outdated, the `Continuation` API has changed to declaring a single `resumeWith(Result)` function, where `Result` is an inline class, and failure is represented with an internal `Failure` class.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik okay, so what is the correct approach? Or is it now impossible what the OP wants to do?

Comment: @akarnokd Last time I tried to resume a continuation from Java, I failed. I'd sure like to know if there is a way to do it. I don't fully understand OP's problem, though, since it's not obvious that the output of `toFlowable` involves any suspendable functions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The idea behind the first link works, but requires a bit more code. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60057482/61158).

Comment: @akarnokd I'm aware of that answer, of course, but it doesn't achieve the goal. It just adds more Kotlin code that is accessible from Java because it no longer involves continuations.

Comment: What goal? You'll have to use Kotlin code to bridge back the Kotlin feature. You may have to create a Kotlin library for that if the codebase of `foo` is outside of your control.

Comment: @akarnokd `Here is an SO answer about mimicking the continuation:` --- this is the topic of our conversation. Calling a `suspend fun` from Java, not writing Kotlin code that calls it and is in turn callable from Java.

Comment: Somebody has to write Kotlin code so if you don't want to, I suggest you open an issue in [the official coroutines project](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues) about the situation.

Comment: @akarnokd What exactly is your suggestion? To open an issue stating that a `suspend fun` is no longer callable from Java and that someone should write some Kotlin code to make it possible? I can only reiterate that the topic of the current conversation is calling a `suspend fun` as a Java method (which, BTW, it is). My suspicion is that you think the topic is something else.

Comment: My suggestion is, open an issue about being unable to call suspend func from Java because the associated components don't work by using only Java. As for the topic, it is about getting a `Flowable` out of a `Flow` into Java, isn't it? I provided a way of doing it that involves support code in Kotlin. It gets the job done, unless I'm mistaken and the objective is not to solve a problem by tools available.

Comment: @akarnokd We had a topic different from the question in our conversation, but yes, OP's problem can be solved by double-wrapping into a `CompletableFuture<Flowable>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to sneak out the returned `Foo<Bar>` from the coroutine in Kotlin:

```
// SomeSuspendAPI.kt
// -----------------

// the method to convert
suspend fun <T> Flow<T>.foo() : Flow<Int> {
    return flow { emit(0) }
}

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun <T> Flow<T>.fooRx() : CompletableFuture<Flowable<Int>> {
    val self = this
    val future = CompletableFuture<Flowable<Int>>()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            future.complete(self.foo().asFlowable())
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            future.completeExceptionally(ex);
        }
    }
    return future
}

// Demo purposes
fun <T> just(v: T) = flow { emit(v) }
```

Then you can use that within Java:

```java
public class UseFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeSuspendAPIKt.fooRx(
                SomeSuspendAPIKt.just(1)
        )
        .thenAccept(flowable -> flowable.subscribe(System.out::println))
        .join();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

You can, of course move some code back to the kotlin side:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.fooRx2() : Flowable<Int> {
    val self = this
    val subject = SingleSubject.create<Flowable<Int>>()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            subject.onSuccess(self.foo().asFlowable())
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            subject.onError(ex)
        }
    }
    return subject.flatMapPublisher { it }
}
```

Then

```java
public class UseFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SomeSuspendAPIKt.fooRx2(SomeSuspendAPIKt.just(1))
                .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

You can generalize this by using a transformation on the Kotlin side which gets you a continuation object to pass along:

```
fun <T, R: Any> Flow<T>.transformAsync(fn: suspend (t: Flow<T>) -> Flow<R>) : Flowable<R> {
    val self = this
    val subject = SingleSubject.create<Flowable<R>>()
    GlobalScope.launch {
        try {
            val r = fn(self).asFlowable();
            subject.onSuccess(r)
        } catch (ex: Throwable) {
            subject.onError(ex)
        }
    }
    return subject.flatMapPublisher { it }
}
```

```java
public class UseFoo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SomeSuspendAPIKt.transformAsync(
                SomeSuspendAPIKt.just(1),
                (source, cont) -> SomeSuspendAPIKt.foo(source, cont)
        )
        .blockingSubscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```