# Can't call Kotlin coroutines code from java code

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

In build.gradle;

```
ext.KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION = '1.3.0-M1'
```

in app/build.gradle:

i

```
mplementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter:0.9.2'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$KOTLIN_COROUTINE_VERSION"
```

In my Android app I has Kotlin code in **TestActivity.kt** :

```
val traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val traidersListDeffered = traderMonitorRestClient.getTraidersList2()
            try {
                val response: Response<List<Trader>> = traidersListDeffered.await()
                // call after return response (e.g. after 10 seconds)
                Debug.d(TAG, "onCreate_after_wait")
                if (response.isSuccessful) { // Returns true if {@link #code()} is in the range [200..300). */
                    val responseAsString = response.body().toString()
                } else {
                    Debug.d(TAG, "onCreate_response_error = $response.code()")
                }
            } catch (e: HttpException) {
                Debug.e(TAG, e.message, e)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                Debug.e(TAG, e.message, e)
            }
        }
    }
```

Nice. It's work fine.

Now I want to use same code in java file - **TradersViewModel.java**

I try this:

```
    import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers;
    import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope;

public class TradersViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private void loadData() {
            TraderMonitorRestClient traderMonitorRestClient = RestClientFactory.createRestClient(TraderMonitorRestClient.class);
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.getMain()) {

            }
        }

}
```

But I has compile error:

```
Cannot resolve method 'launch(kotlinx.coroutines.MainCoroutineDispatcher)
```

Comment: May Be [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class) will help .. I never tried it myself..

Comment: Just wondering - why won't you kotlinize your java file?

Comment: @r2rek I convert to kotlin code and now work fine.