# Call Kotlin coroutine builder from Java class

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

Android studio 3.4

In my android project:

Assume we have the following suspend function:

**Test1.kt**

```
import retrofit2.Response

suspend fun login(email: String, password: String): Response<*> {
```

and use it in **Test2.kt**

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val response: Response<*> = Test1.login("aa", "bb")
    if (response.isSuccessful) { 

    } else { 

    }
}
```

And it's work fine.
Nice.

Now I want to call this function `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)` in one of my existing Java classes (which I'm not able to convert to Kotlin for now)

How I can do this?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class). Head there for answers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class)