# How to test a kotlin suspend function with Spock (groovy)

Tags: kotlin, groovy, spock, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following kotlin suspending function:

`suspend fun registerNewTransaction(transaction: String): String`

I am trying to test it through [Spock](http://spockframework.org/), but I have not found the way to call this kotlin suspending function without specifying the `Continuation<? super String>` parameter since Groovy identifies the kotlin container class as Java class.
I would like to know if it is possible to call suspending functions from another JVM-based language, otherwise I will have to use another testing library like JUnit.

Comment: It would be interesting to learn what you ended up doing. It might help other Kotlin and/or Spock users. :-)

Comment: @kriegaex, one year ago I had to work in a Kotlin project that used JUnit and Spek as testing libraries. Now I am working in a Java project and they implement Spock as test library and I realized how powerful and descriptive it is, I wanted to implement it with Kotlin as Kotlin is my favorite programming language now. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :-) It explains your motivation but does not answer my question about what you ended up doing (your decision/solution how to proceed).

Comment: @kriegaex Hi, have any clue now? I'm very interested in Spock with Kotlin.

Answer (score 4):

You can mock that Continuation object, which kotlin is compiling into the method call. This code worked for me:

```
// mocked continuation
def continuation = Mock(Continuation) {
  getContext() >> Mock(CoroutineContext)
}

// method call which should be tested
subjectUnderTest.suspendableMethod(someParameter, continuation)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @julianwki will break once running something like: `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { /* ... /*/ }`

A more robust version is to run with an actual `CoroutineContext` rather than mocking it:

```kotlin
def continuation = Mock(Continuation) {
    getContext() >> Dispatchers.Default
}
```

I assume it is somehow possible to create a `Continuation` through calling `TestScopeKt.TestScope(EmptyCoroutineContext.INSTANCE)` (`org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test`), since that seems to be what what the underlying `runTest` is using. However, I newer found a good way to reach that point.

Also be aware that mocking `Continuation` we do not have an implementation for `fun resumeWith(result: Result<T>)` which so far does not seem to be an issue, but might be in the future. Finding a completely non-mocked solution is probably desirable.

Additionally, if calling a suspend function from Groovy/Spock one might be out of luck. I did try the solutions suggested on: [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class) and similar "hacks" without any luck, if calling them directly from Groovy. One might be able to make a Kotlin wrapper for each single call needed, however, in my case at least it is not viable

Answer (score 0):

> if it is possible to call suspending functions from another JVM-based
>   language

It's possible, but you need to pass `Continuation` as last parameter, since it's how Kotlin compiles `suspend` functions

I'd suggest using Kotlin for testing Kotlin code, there are a lot of Kotlin-specific libraries like `mockk` that support coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

I used this question as a reference [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class)
and added this function in my code

```
fun <T> await(block: suspend () -> T): T =
  GlobalScope.future { block.invoke() }.get()
```

and use it this way:

```
await {
  myService.mySuspendedFunction(myArguments, it)
}
```

where `it` is a `kotlin.coroutines.Continuation` object