# accessing kotlin Suspend function from Java code

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I have Room database interface which is a Kotlin file and as I dont want the calls to run on mainthread I am using kotlin `Suspend`. how can I use suspend function from java

I have two method where I want to insert a `User` and another to retrieve the users

these are the errors I get in my java file

[image]

Code

Room Dao interface

UserDao

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {

    fun getAllUsersAsync(): CompletableFuture<List<User>> =
        GlobalScope.future { getAllUsers() }

    @Query("SELECT * FROM user")
    suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User>

    @Insert
    suspend fun insertUser(user: User): Long
}
```

Java code

```
private Long addUser(com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User user) {
    return userDao.insertUser(user);
}

private List<com.i6systems.in2plane.AppDatabase.User> getUsers () {
    return userDao.getAllUsersAsync();
}
```

your help is much appreciated

Thanks
R

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class)

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm new to `Coroutines`, but `return userDao.insertUser(user.await());` should do the job.

Comment: I had a look at that already, but that does not solve my question on Java file

Comment: Also i recommend this KotlinConf: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hfBv0a09Jc it's nice piece of knowledge and also second part called "deep dive into Coroutines".

Comment: IIRC you have to take and pass the current continuation object (of the coroutine) to call a suspend function

Comment: @AnimeshSahu can you give an example please

Comment: @BRDroid check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803893/11377112, grab continuation from the launch block or async block, because they(continuation) are created when creating a new coroutine.

Comment: Maybe my gist help you https://gist.github.com/zarini/c70401f48a953b09e64912e0d6b3dfcb