# Continuation<? super String> cannot be applied to ()

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to access a method in a kotlin class from a Java class.

Heres my kotlin class

```
import drewcarlson.coingecko.CoinGeckoService
import io.ktor.client.HttpClient
import io.ktor.client.engine.okhttp.OkHttp

class coinprice {
    val httpClient = HttpClient(OkHttp)
    val coinGecko = CoinGeckoService(httpClient)

    suspend fun pricefunction(): String {
        val price = coinGecko.getTokenPrice("ethereum","0xa44e5137293e855f8cd796ffcb037",
                "USD").toString();
        return price
    }
}
```

In my java class i call using

```
coinprice price = new coinprice();
String test = price.pricefunction();
```

It gives me an error saying

```
price.pricefunction();
            ^
 required: Continuation<? super String>
 found: no arguments
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58803893/11882002) includes a Java implementation, and the accepted one requires you to simply make a small function in your Kotlin codebase to help you

Comment: Your `pricefunction` runs asynchronously and thus doesn't immediatly return the `String` but a transport object `Continuation<String>` which will only yield a `String` when the call to coinGecko has succeded