# Convert Kotlin `suspend fun` to Java

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to convert a library from Kotlin to Java but this method put a lid on me:

```
private suspend fun queryPurchases() {
        val inappResult: PurchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        processPurchases(inappResult.purchasesList, isRestore = true)
        val subsResult: PurchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
        processPurchases(subsResult.purchasesList, isRestore = true)
    }
```

How to approach a `suspend fun` in Java??

Comment: I'm curious, what are the reasons for porting to Java? The easiest way for this would be to write the wrapping code in Kotlin and declare a non-suspending API, for instance using futures. But that relies on being "allowed" to write some Kotlin code, hence my question.

Comment: Wait, do you want to *call* suspend functions from Java? Or *convert* them? If you convert a suspend function, you will probably just move the problem one step further because that function will likely be calling other suspend functions. If that's the case, are you converting everything?

Comment: Actually the thing I mentioned in my first comment has already been described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class

Comment: I am converting the library to Java because I like it more than Kotlin. Also, I want to add new functionality and it would be easier for me to maintain it because I am more familiar with Java than Kotlin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suspendable functions are a feature added by Kotlin and exclusive to it. You can't easily create or even invoke suspend functions in Java.

You could just ignore the fact that the original function was suspendable and treat it as a regular function, but if the library used coroutines extensively, it could be hard to port it to Java.

Answer (score 2):

Closest thing in Java is a probably a [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) or a [Reactive Stream](https://www.reactive-streams.org).

[Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io) from the Spring ecosystem is a popular Reactive Streams implementation.

Whatever technology you use, porting in a way that preserves the concurrency of the original code is probably not going to be straightforward.