# Kotlin suspend function not executing after delay when called from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to call this Kotlin suspend code from my Java class. The solution is based on what is mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887677/5140533

Kotlin Code:

`Main.kt`

```kotlin
suspend fun doWorld() = coroutineScope {
    launch {
        println("Thread name2 ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(2000L)
        println("Hello world")
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
fun doSomethingAsync() =
    GlobalScope.future { doWorld() }
```

`Converter.java`

```java
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MainKt.doSomethingAsync();
    }
}
```

When I call `doSomethingAsync()` from my Java class, I do not see any of the print statements. Can somebody please explain what exactly is going on and how I can correct this.

Comment: could you show how are you calling it from java?

Comment: @Sergey I updated the code and added the java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your case the program completes before a new coroutine starts. Try to delay the current `Main Thread` in the `main` function after calling `MainKt.doSomethingAsync()`:

```
public class Converter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MainKt.doSomethingAsync();
       try {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(2500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Or use MainKt.doSomethingAsync().get()
    }
}
```

Then I guess the logs will be displayed.

Comment: Because `GlobalScope.future` returns a `CompletableFuture`, you could instead use `MainKt.doSomethingAsync().get();`, which will wait only exactly as long as it needs to.

Comment: @sam Tried that and it worked. Thanks!