# Emit data to kotlin's flow from regular java function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

I have an external interface which I cannot change:

```
interface ExternalApi {
    fun onDataReceived(data: String)
}
```

I need to start consuming data and send it to `flow`. Data order is a necessity. I'd like to have a cold `flow`, but I couldn't find a version of cold `flow` with `emit` function, so I used hot `flow` + replay set to Max value as a workaround. Here was my first try:

```
class FlowProblem {
    val flow: MutableSharedFlow<String> = MutableSharedFlow(replay = Int.MAX_VALUE)

    fun startConsuming() {
        object : ExternalApi {
            override fun onDataReceived(data: String) {
                flow.emit(data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as `emit` function is a suspended function. However this is an external interface and I cannot add suspend modifier. I tried to also do something like this:

```
override fun onDataReceived(data: String) {
    val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Job())
    coroutineScope.launch {
        flow.emit(data)
    }
}
```

but for me it's kind a silly to create new coroutine only in order to move data to flow. I'm also wondering about data order.

What should I do? Maybe flow/channel is not suitable here and I should pick something another?

Comment: I think you need [callbackFlow](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/callback-flow.html) instead of SharedFlow and emit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class maybe it is that you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks IR42, `callbackFlow` was exactly what I needed.