# How to call Kotlin suspend function from Java

Tags: java, kotlin

I have no experience with Kotlin and I am faced with having to write a function in Kotlin because my understanding is that the API I need is not available in Java. I tried 2 ways to call the function with no success. Can someone help me to correct this? Here is the relevant code.

```
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.health.connect.client.HealthConnectClient
import androidx.health.connect.client.records.StepsRecord
import androidx.health.connect.client.request.ReadRecordsRequest
import androidx.health.connect.client.time.TimeRangeFilter
import java.time.Instant

class StepCounter {
    private var count: Long = 0

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    suspend fun getCount(): Long {
        val healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient

        healthConnectClient = HealthConnectClient.getOrCreate(App.context)
        val response =
            healthConnectClient.readRecords(
                ReadRecordsRequest(
                    StepsRecord::class,
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(Instant.now(), Instant.MAX)
                )
            )
        for (stepRecord in response.records) {
            count += stepRecord.count
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

[Here is one attempt to call the function with the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPCmV.png)

[Here is another way I tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzMK3.png)

Comment: you sort of can't call a `suspend` function from java directly. The second attempt is closer but you should either use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class to make a java compatible version out of it or simply not use suspend for code that is meant to be shared across languages.

Comment: Instead of embedding links that may or may not remain valid, please embed code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class)