# Android - Suspend Kotlin Function Called From Java Never Executed

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to use the accept answer here. [Call Kotlin suspend function in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52869672/call-kotlin-suspend-function-in-java-class) , `innerReadStepsByTimeRange` this one is never called but debug was able to stop at the `readStepsByTimeRange`.

**My Kotlin class (the one that is called from java)**

```
class StepReaderUtils {

companion object {
    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    fun readStepsByTimeRange(
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) : CompletableFuture<Long> = GlobalScope.future {
        innerReadStepsByTimeRange(healthConnectClient, startTime, endTime)
    }

    private suspend fun innerReadStepsByTimeRange (
        healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
        startTime: Instant,
        endTime: Instant
    ) : Long {
        var totalStepsCount = 0L
        val response =
            healthConnectClient.readRecords(
                ReadRecordsRequest(
                    StepsRecord::class,
                    timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime)
                )
            )
        for (stepRecord in response.records) {
            totalStepsCount += stepRecord.count;
        }
        return totalStepsCount
    }
}

}
```

**My java caller method**

```
CompletableFuture<Long> totalStepsCountCF = StepReaderUtils.Companion.readStepsByTimeRange(
            healthConnectClient, startDate, endDate);
    return totalStepsCountCF.get();
```

My Gradle module build

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0'
    implementation "androidx.health.connect:connect-client:1.0.0-alpha08"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8:1.6.4"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"
```

What am i doing wrong?