# Kotlin - how return value from withContext to java code?

Tags: java, android, flutter, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing an app on Flutter, but I use platform-dependent code on Kotlin (android) and Java. This is my code:

```
  suspend fun check() : Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) 
  {
     //some network logic
     //init time value
     return@withContext time != -1L;
   }
```

next i need to call this function in java code but i don't know how to do it.  I tried it, but I have error :

```
  if(call.method.equals("check")){   
     //issue in this line - check()                            
     final state = ServiceManager.INSTANCE.check();
     result.success(state);
  }
```

I'm new to Kotlin, how do I return the value from withContext(Dispatchers.IO) and using it in Java code?

I will be very grateful

Comment: Global Scopes are never intended to return any result. They are like fire and forget. Use withContext to return values but dont forget to make fun a suspend fun.

Comment: I don’t know Flutter, but you need to find a way to get the result asynchronously instead of synchronously, such as using a callback. Or this function at least needs to be called from a thread other than the UI thread, in which case you could safely use `runBlocking` instead of `GlobalScope.launch`.

Comment: @VivekGupta I don't think `GlobalScope` has anything to do with returning or not returning. Use `GlobalScope.async()` and it is no longer a fire and forget, you can get the result. Use `myOwnScope.launch()` and do not store the resulting `Job` and this is a fire and (almost) forget.

Comment: @broot yes it should be lauch instead of Global scope

Comment: @fetFrumos see this answer of how to call suspend function from java code bade https://stackoverflow.com/a/52887677/15754377